# Можно ли в Java вызвать событие вручную?

Tags: java, javafx

```
c.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                        if (!isClicked(c)) {
                            c.setBackground(null);
                            c.setEffect(null);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Пробовал так, но ругается на неправильный тип:

```
c.getOnMouseExited().handle(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c.fireEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, ...));
```

или

```
Event.fireEvent(c, new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, ...));
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, Вы не озвучили самое простое решение:  сохранить реализацию в промежуточную переменную/поле eventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(); После чего, в любом доступном месте вызывать, как пример: eventHandler.handle(null);